# Physics Solver to find equation in $R$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I’m retired and an amateur.  Is there an online physics (or math?) solver which will help me.  I’ve posed a binary orbit problem which I can’t solve correctly, getting several contradictory equations. Ideally, I want a final equation for $R$, the radius of one star’s
orbit with another star, given their masses, m1 & m2, and the orbital angular momentum H of that star. Ie: I’m not interested in a numerical answer, but the final correct equation itself.

Comment: Kepler's third law works for two stars too.

Answer (score 2):

This should be an introductory physics problem, so make sure you're not overcomplicating things! The two keys are to think of things in a center of mass frame, and to use the assumption of circular motion which gives a force balance equation $F_g=m \omega^2 r$, which says that the force due to gravity is balanced by the centrifugal force.

I'll write out the system of equations where I consider masses $m_1,m_2$, positions $\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2$, magnitudes $r_1=\|\vec{r}_1\|$, $r_2=\|\vec{r}_2\|$, total radius $R=r_1+r_2$, and an angular velocity $\omega$.

Then:

- $m_1 r_1=m_2 r_2$
- $R=r_1+r_2$
- $\frac{Gm_1 m_2}{R^2}=m_1 \omega^2 r_1$ (circular force balance)

We can use these three equations to eliminate the variables $r_1$ and $r_2$, and solve for $R$ in terms of $\omega$ to get

$$R=\left(\frac{G (m_1+m_2)}{\omega^2}\right)^{1/3}$$

If we want things in terms of the total angular momentum $L=m_1 r_1^2 \omega+m_2 r_2^2 \omega$, we could eliminate $\omega$ as well:

$$R=\frac{L^2(m_1+m_2)}{G m_1^2 m_2^2}$$

This might be easier to read or interpret in terms of the reduced mass $\mu=m_1 m_2/(m_1+m_2)$ and total mass $M=m_1+m_2$:

$$R=\frac{L^2}{G \mu^2 M}=\left(\frac{G M}{\omega^2}\right)^{1/3}$$

The easiest way to get contradictory equations in a situation like this would be to plug in values of $R$ and $L$ that would lead to a non-circular orbit. The fact that $R\propto L^2$ in this situation is quite stringent.

---

Note: to solve the equations, you can use Mathematica. For $L_1=m_1 r_1^2 \omega$ we have:

`Solve[{m1 r1==m2 r2, R==r1+r2, G m1 m2 /R^2==m1 omega^2 r1, L1==m1 r1^2 omega},{r1,r2,R,omega}]`
$$R = \frac{L_1^2 (m_1 + m_2)^3}{G m_1^2 m_2^4}$$

Using a computer to solve the equations isn't cheating and helps clarify all the ingredients going in and coming out!

Comment: To David...thanks very much.  In my particular case I wanted L to be not the total orbital angular momentum, but the orbital angular momentum for just one of the masses.  I will study what you posted.  Gene

Comment: @user86742 I added that case, we still have $R\propto L_1^2$ just with a different constant.